# execute commands on my local server before execute the stages on docker - gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

i have this gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - test

test_ahpi:
  stage: test
  image: "ahgora/alpine-test-node"
  script:
   - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/api; npm install --unsafe-perm
   - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/api; node_modules/.bin/gulp build-test

test_php:
  stage: test
  image: "ahgora/alpine-test-php"
  script:
   - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/; make test
```

but i wanted to do some steps on the local server before, so i dont need to run some steps manually.

is there a way to execute commands on my local server before execute the stages on gitlab-ci.yml??

I thought i could do something like below, but i get error for not have any defined image to this step.(but i want to run it in shell not in docker this specific stage).

```
stages:
  - prepare
  - test

docker:
  stage: prepare
  script:
   - docker run -d --name lookupd nsqio/nsq /nsqlookupd
   - docker run --name mongo -d mongo
   - docker run -d --link lookupd:lookupd --name nsqd nsqio/nsq /nsqd --broadcast-address=lookupd --lookupd-tcp-address=lookupd:4160
   - docker run --name redis -d redis    

test_ahpi:
  stage: test
  image: "ahgora/alpine-test-node"
  script:
   - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/api; npm install --unsafe-perm
   - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/api; node_modules/.bin/gulp build-test

test_php:
  stage: test
  image: "ahgora/alpine-test-php"
  script:
   - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/; make test
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use docker as the gitlab-runner , then you can specify `tag` in the particular stage and specify shell as the executor.